# Standard Complete Model of ZFC and Reflection

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

I am reading *Levy's Axiom Schemata of Strong Infinity in Axiomatic Set Theory*. In theorem 6, which says that this Reflection principle $N_0$ is equivalent to Replacement + Infinity in $ZF$ (in $S$ which is $ZF$ minus Replacement + Infinity, to be more precise), he skips the step from $N_0$ to Infinity & Replacement, which is the interesting part for me. Instead, Levy refers to a book by Montague and Feferman, *The method of arithmetization and some of it's applications*, that was never finished, as far as I know. ([see bottom part of page 8](https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/arithmetization.pdf))

This $N_0$ says the following:
$$
\exists u(Scm^S(u) \& \forall x_1, \ldots, x_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n \in u \& \varphi \iff Rel(u, \varphi)))
$$
*Definition 1* from said paper says that $\alpha$ is called inaccessible iff $R(\alpha)$ ($V_\alpha$ in today's notation) is a standard complete model of ZF.

**My question is**:
How can this possibly hold? Does is not violate Gödel's incompleteness?

Levy says he uses formulation of ZF axioms in *non-simple applied first-order functional calculus*, which sounds like second-order logic to me, but that still shouldn't allow him to prove the existence of inaccessibles, right?

What am I missing? Any help or further reference would be very appreciated, I'm stuck for several weeks already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that the reflection theorem doesn't provide an $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ satisfies all of ZFC; rather, the reflection theorem provides, for each theorem $\varphi$ of ZFC, an $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha$ satisfies $\varphi$. So we're not getting inaccessibles from reflection.

Second, note that while each *instance* of the reflection theorem is provable in ZFC - that is, for each theorem $\varphi$ of $ZFC$, $ZFC$ proves "There is some $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models\varphi$" - ZFC does *not* prove "Every instance of the reflection theorem holds" (indeed, that's not even expressible!).

Finally, the proof of the above claim - that ZFC proves each instance of reflection - takes place in a metatheory slightly stronger than ZFC. So there is no contradiction.

A more modern source, like Jech's book, might be clearer about these things.

Comment: In Jech, Reflection really is a scheme and that makes sense to me.
What I'm insterested in is this particular Levy's reflection which is often cited as being 'the original'. I have found no indications that it is a meta-statement. Also, I don't see why would he prove a meta-statement in ZF, which is what he does.
See [link](http://msp.org/pjm/1960/10-1/pjm-v10-n1-p14-s.pdf) (it's not password protected so I assume it's legal to share. .) )

Comment: @mikulas For each specific $\varphi$, we get a precise statement in the language; but the principle $N$, which is "For all $\varphi$, . . .", is a meta-statement. Or, put another way, $N$ is a *scheme* of sentences in the object language, and statements e.g. comparing $N$ and $N'$ are meta-statements.

Comment: Levy says in the very beginning of said paper that he uses functional calculus, which seems to be what we now call second-order logic that allows me to use quantifiers over formulas. But even if $N_0$ is a scheme, each instance of it contains the predicate $\exists u (Scm^S(u))$ which is equivalent to $\exists \alpha (In(\alpha))$ since $Scm^S(V_\alpha) \iff In(\alpha)$ (Definition 1). So I think he says he proves existence of $In(\alpha)$ from ZF. That's very confusing.

Comment: I must be missing something, probably precise meaning of $Scm^Q(u)$, because when Kanamori speaks about reflection in *Levy and set theory*, he refers to this 1960 paper and introduces the usual formulation of reflection from Jech or Kanamori's The Higher Infinite.

Comment: Since $S$ doesn't have the axioms of infinity and replacement, its standard complete models are $V_\alpha$ for all limit ordinals $\alpha$.  The fact that ZFC proves each instance of the reflection principle $N_0$ in the question won't need a metatheory stronger than ZFC; it should be formalizable in Peano Arithmetic (with room to spare).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you elaborate on what you mean by the slightly stronger than $\operatorname{ZFC}$-metatheory? I don't see how that metatheory would look like and I don't even see why you would want to step outside of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ to prove that every instance of reflection holds.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, that sounds like a silly mistake I made. Too bad you only wrote it as a comment. I'll try to verify it and mark the question as solved if it's really correct.
Also thanks to everybody and their advice.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding inaccessibles, the usual (modern) def'n of a weakly inaccessible cardinal is an uncountable regular limit cardinal, and a strongly inaccessible cardinal is an uncountable regular strong-limit cardinal.

If ZFC is consistent then the existence of an inaccessible is not a theorem of ZFC, because if $k$ is inaccessible then  $(V_k)^L$ is a model of ZFC (where $L$ is Godel's constructible class). Adding an axiom that there is an inaccessible is analogous to the axiom of Infinity, which implies the consistency of Peano Arithmetic.

See "Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs", by Kenneth Kunen. There are also 2 books by Jech on set theory that I am not familiar with, but have a good reputation.